# Java programming giving error "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout

This project is a java quiz in a jpanel. When trying to compile the program I get this error. It seems something is wrong with my gidlayout, but i used it in another program and it work perfectly.

Error:

```
QuizGUI.java:53: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor GridLayout(int,int,int,int,int)
location: class java.awt.GridLayout
JPanel questionPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 10, 0));
^
QuizGUI.java:89: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method createEmptyBorder(int,int,int,int,int)
location: class javax.swing.BorderFactory
mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(ebGap, ebGap, ebGap, ebGap, ebGap));
```

Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ButtonModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class QuizGUI{

private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
private Question[] questions =
{
new Question("What percent is the earth made up of water?","70", new String[]
{
"80", "85", "50", "69"
}),
new Question("How many months in a year?", "12", new String[]
{
"1", "Several", "100", "Heck if I know?"
}),
new Question("Who was buried in Grant's Tomb?", "Grant", new String[]
{
"Washington", "Jefferson", "Lincoln", "Mickey Mouse"
}),
new Question("What's the air-speed velocity of a fully ladden swallow",
"African or European?", new String[]
{
"100 mi/hr", "25 mi/hr", "50 mi/hr", "-10 mi/hr"
}),
new Question("What color was Washington's white horse?", "White",
new String[]
{
"Blue", "Brown", "Chartreuse", "Mauve"
})
};
private QuestionGUI[] questionGuis = new QuestionGUI[questions.length];

public QuizGUI()
{
JPanel questionPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 10, 0));
for (int i = 0; i < questionGuis.length; i++)
{
questionGuis[i] = new QuestionGUI(questions[i]);
JComponent comp = questionGuis[i].getComponent();
comp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
questionPanel.add(comp);
}


JButton checkAnswersBtn = new JButton("CheckAnswers");
checkAnswersBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
int score = 0;
for (QuestionGUI quest : questionGuis)
{
if (quest.isSelectionCorrect())
{
score++;
}
else
{
System.out.println("For the question: \"" + quest.getQuestion().getQuestion() + "\",");
System.out.println("\"" + quest.getSelectedString() + "\" is the wrong answer");
System.out.println("The correct answer is: \"" + quest.getQuestion().getCorrectAnswer() + "\"");
}
}
System.out.println("Score: " + score);
}
});
JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
btnPanel.add(checkAnswersBtn);

int ebGap = 10;
mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(ebGap, ebGap, ebGap, ebGap, ebGap));
mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
mainPanel.add(questionPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
mainPanel.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

public JComponent getComponent()
{
return mainPanel;
}

private static void createAndShowUI()
{
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Quiz");
frame.getContentPane().add(new QuizGUI().getComponent());
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
public void run()
{
createAndShowUI();
}
});
}
}

class QuestionGUI
{
private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
private Question question;
private ButtonGroup buttonGrp = new ButtonGroup();

public QuestionGUI(Question question)
{
this.question = question;

JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 10, 0));
for (String str : question.getAnswers())
{
JRadioButton rButton = new JRadioButton(str);
rButton.setActionCommand(str);
radioPanel.add(rButton);
buttonGrp.add(rButton);
}
mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
mainPanel.add(new JLabel(question.getQuestion(), SwingConstants.LEFT), 
BorderLayout.NORTH);
mainPanel.add(radioPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public Question getQuestion()
{
return question;
}

public String getSelectedString()
{
ButtonModel model = buttonGrp.getSelection();
if (model != null)
{
return model.getActionCommand();
}
else
return null;
}

public boolean isSelectionCorrect()
{
ButtonModel model = buttonGrp.getSelection();
if (model != null)
{
return question.isCorrect(model.getActionCommand());
}
return false;
}

public JComponent getComponent()
{
return mainPanel;
}
}

class Question
{
private String question;
private String answer;
private List<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();

public Question(String q, String answer, String[] badAnswers)
{
question = q;
this.answer = answer;
for (String string : badAnswers)
{
answers.add(string);
}
answers.add(answer);
Collections.shuffle(answers);
}

public String getQuestion()
{
return question;
}

public String[] getAnswers()
{
return answers.toArray(new String[0]);
}

public String getCorrectAnswer()
{
return answer;
}

public boolean isCorrect(String selection)
{
return answer.equals(selection);
}
}
```

I am so confused why this is going on. I almost did the same thing for another project and it work and no the gridlayout is broken.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better than format the code plus put only the relevant part.

Comment: No reason to panic, just read the error message carefully. It is rather descriptive, certainly if you compare it with the javadoc/API you are trying to use

Answer (score 2):

You are passing five arguments to createEmptyBorder in your code:

```
mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(ebGap, ebGap, ebGap, ebGap, ebGap));
```

but it actually takes four: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html#createEmptyBorder%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: Oh wow, I did not see that.. Thanks so much!! But now im having a new error

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Question
 at QuizGUI.<init>(QuizGUI.java:23)
 at QuizGUI.createAndShowUI(QuizGUI.java:98)
 at QuizGUI.access$100(QuizGUI.java:20)
 at QuizGUI$2.run(QuizGUI.java:111)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:646)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:607)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:605)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Answer (score 2):

1) `new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 10, 0)` [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) has [only four parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

2) `EmptyBorder(int,int,int,int,int)` [EmptyBorder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) has [only four parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/EmptyBorder.html)

Answer (score 2):

You're passing five int values to the GridLayout constructor. I checked the API and there is no constructor that takes five values - there is one that takes four.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/